# Confused with this Kmap

Tags: flip-flop, karnaugh-map

[image]

Its a 3 variable kmap ABC, I need to solve this for the design of a JK counter and I'm stuck on how to solve this? please help

Comment: Could you label which is A B and C? Or does the order not matter?

Comment: Sorry about that, so the left will be A' and A, the top B' B, and bottom C' C C'. Both kmaps are ABC

Comment: So both top and bottom are for the same ABC or is it suppose to be two different components linked with the same input of ABC?

Comment: Both are kmaps are ABC, treat them as separate ABC kmaps

Answer (score 0):

Using [this web site](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/), you get the following diagrams and minimized expressions:

[image]

[image]